# How to add button and Action in User Order Information

Tags: magento-1.9, customer

Can somebody please help me and give me information how to add custom button in Magento (1.9) customer order review ? I want to add button with send e-mail Action , i want to add e-mail content in backend so i don't need any input. I want only add action to button

I added button in `app/desing/frontend/base/default/template/sales/order/view.phptml`

this is code:

```
<p><a class="btn btn-warning" href="#">Send e-mail Action</a></p>
<div class="buttons-set">
    <p class="back-link"><a href="<?php echo $this->getBackUrl() ?>"><small>&laquo; </small><?php echo $this->getBackTitle() ?></a></p>
</div>
```

Now my questions

Can somebody please tell me how and where add Action function to this button ?.
I will handle myself with all code but i want to now where to put all code.

Answer (score 1):

Best approach would be, you will need to develop an extension for this because you will need to call `action` function.

For creating simple extension to be able to call your action, [check this link](http://inchoo.net/magento/programming-magento/magento-hello-world-module-extension/).

Basically, you will be calling the function (for ex. `public function yourAction()`) which is in your own controller file.

Comment: Thanks for answer @Adarsh Khatri , but I don't want to make extension for admin site . I want to make extension for user site after login .

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood, please check my updated answer.